Confusion about Intrinsic goodness/value and the ought of fittingness as put in The Oxford Handbook of Value Theory
In section 3.2 "Doubts about the Fundamentality of Intrinsic Value" Jonas Olson provides Moores "definition" of intrinsic value

for a thing to be intrinsically good is
for it to be such that “it ought to exist for its own sake” (Moore 1993 [1903]: 34), or for it
to be such that it would be good even if it were to exist in complete isolation (Moore 1993
[1903]: § 112, p. 236; cf. §§ 55, 57, pp. 145, 147).

and explains one of Moores points in Principia about intrinsic goodness in the following way:

We thus arrive at two Moorean theses about the fundamentality of the concept of intrinsic goodness: First, it is unanalyzable. Second, it is the sole unanalyzable concept in ethics; all other ethical concepts are analyzable in terms of it. Let us call these two theses Unanalyzability and Uniqueness

Now here is where my confusion starts. Later in 3.3, it is mentioned that

C. D. Broad and A. C. Ewing both suggested that intrinsic value is analyzable in terms of the ought of fittingness (Broad 1942; Ewing 1939, 1947). According to such a “fitting attitude analysis,” for an object to be intrinsically good is for that object to be a fitting object of a pro-attitude.

Then, it talks about problems with such a fitting attitude view since somtimes we ought to take up such an attitude even if doing so has nothing to do with the objects intrinsic value. So, it is asked

How should we understand the fittingness sense of “ought,” then? What is it for an attitude to be fitting? One suggestion is that for an attitude of a certain kind to an object of a certain kind to be fitting is for that attitude to be intrinsically good (Hurka 2003: 604). For example, a negative attitude to a malicious demon may be intrinsically good.

My question/confusion is: what even is this fittingness being talked about? My confusion is that it sounds like we are saying that being intrinsically good = fitting object of a pro-attitude, but to be fitting depends on if that thing is intrinsically good. If that is true, then what is even being said? That we just should have certain attitudes towards things just because that's the way it is for some reason? That seems like a terrible argument...
What is even more confusing is that later in response to Judith Jarvis Thomson, Olson mentions that

Consider, for instance, Ewing’s analysis, according to which for a thing, X, to be intrinsically good is for X to be such that we (or anyone who is in a position to do so) ought, in the fittingness sense of “ought,” to take up a pro-attitude toward X for X’s own sake

and

the fact that pleasure is intrinsically good (if it is a fact) yields an
affirmative answer to the question of whether we ought to seek pleasure, because what
it is for something to be intrinsically good is for it to be such that we ought to approve of
it, or take up pro-attitudes toward it (for example, seek it) for its own sake.

which sounds a lot like saying "intrinsically good = X to be such that we (or anyone who is in a position to do so) ought, in the fittingness sense of “ought,” to take up a pro-attitude toward X for X’s own sake". This is suppose to be a rejection to the skeptic who says intrinsic value is a nonsense concept, but this analysis just seems to support that (given that you also think that “just plain ought” etc also are nonsense). And so I am left scratching my head at this section since it says a lot about fittingness yet hardly says what it is in a non-circular sounding way, or in a way that does not skip over the problem of how for its own sake makes any sense at all beyond the lame "it is what it is and I will frown at you if you ask me why" response. Is there something I am missing or is that just a problem of the kind of theory proposed here?

I'm not familiar with those philosophers so don't know, but (1) even philosophers are not always consistent or coherent, so the general assumption of coherence -- needed for reading/interpretation -- may have to be given up, (2) what appears as a circular definition might be due to ambiguity or to concept slippage (especially when sb else is entering the discourse), and (3) what appears as circular definition might be due to a (perhaps implicit) contextual definition where x and y are defined in terms of each other (some of that seems to be visible in the quotes).

@andrós so I did some research and apparently on the SEP they even said that "The distinction between right-kind reasons (RKRs) and WKRs for valuing attitudes can of course be easily drawn by appeal to the property of being valuable simpliciter... But such accounts of the RKR/WKR distinction are of course unavailable to FA theorists, at least insofar as they aspire to provide non-circular accounts of evaluative properties." So if we limit what has intrinsic value to things that are fitting, and things are fitting if they are intrinsically valuable, how is that better than "it is what it is"?
